# Not able write all 32 lines of output in the output file in verilog

Tags: verilog, fwrite, modelsim

I'm trying to write a testbench that will output all the values read and evaluated from a file into a text file. But I can only get a 1 line in the output file instead of the 32 lines. Can someone shed some light?

```
`timescale 100ns/1ps
module multtest;

reg clk,reset;
reg signed [7:0] a, b;
reg signed [15:0] result,res;
integer fread, fw;
reg [7:0] in_a, in_b;
reg [47:0] in_r;
wire signed[15:0] result1;

mult mult_0 (.clk(clk) , .reset(reset), .A(a), .B(b), .result(result1));

initial 
begin 
 fread = $fopen ("goldenresult","r");
fw = $fopen ("goldresult.txt","w");
clk = 1'b0;
reset = 1'b1;
#200; 
reset = 1'b0;
#200;
reset = 1'b1;
end
always 
#2.5 clk = ~clk; 

//conditon for reset
always @ (reset == 1'b1)
begin
a <= 0;
b <= 0;
result <= 0;
end


always @(posedge clk)

begin

//Verifying the result when testmode = 0  and reset = 0

        if (reset == 1'b0) 
            begin

                while ($fscanf(fread, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, result) != 6) begin end

                    $display ("a = %b, b = %b, result = %b", a, b, result);

                    end
            end

/*always @(posedge clk)
@(negedge reset)

if (reset == 1'b0) 
            begin

                while ($fscanf(fread, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, result) != 6) begin end

 $fwrite(fw, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, res);

end*/
endmodule
```

I've commented out the portion of the code that was supposed to write. Am i doing anything wrong. The output is in this format:

a = 10111010, b = 00111011, result = 0000000000000000

Its supposed to write all 32 lines but instead writes only 1. Although it correctly displays the output in modelsim.

Answer (score 1):

This is line `fw = $fopen ("goldresult.txt","w");` create new file for writing or truncate it to zero length. So in your case when you call the `$fwrite(fw, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, res);` function you re-write each time values.

To add new values you need to use another mode `fa = $fopen ("goldresult.txt","a+");` **a+** *(uses for append; open or create for update at end-of-file)*

In code it looks like:

```
fa = $fopen ("goldresult.txt","a+");
$fwrite(fa, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, res);
```

and don't forget to close the file `$fclose(fa);`

Comment: The fa lien is not working and also the fclose doesn't seem to work. I can get the output written onto a .txt file only if i close modelsim. Also the output is not displayed line by line but on the same line. How do i make it appear on different lines?

Comment: Please add full code of all modules, that I can simulate it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way that you are doing the while loop. At the end of the while loop line you have `begin end`. That means that the only thing that happens in the while loop is just the condition that is being tested (`$fscanf`). You also want the `$fwrite` to be in the while loop, so you need to put the `end` after the the write.

The other problem is that you are testing for `!= 6` when instead you should continue the while loop when `== 6`.

You've also said that you'd like a carriage return after each output, so you should use `$fdisplay` instead of `$fwrite`. The only difference between them is the inclusion of a carriage return.

```
while ($fscanf(fread, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, result) == 6) begin
  $fdisplay(fw, "%s = %b, %s = %b, %s = %b", in_a, a, in_b, b, in_r, res);
end
```

Comment: your method doesn't work. I can get the output written onto a .txt file only if i close modelsim. Also the output is not displayed line by line but on the same line. How do i make it appear on different lines?

Comment: I've made the changes to continue the loop while valid data is present "==6" and to insert carriage returns.